CreateOleObject('outlook.application'); causing program to hang
I have an app that reads Outlook info and displays it on my desktop. This has been running OK for 10+ years.
It still works fine on 2 laptops running Windows 10 & 11, but started failing on my Windows 11 desktop a couple of months ago if run whilst Outlook is not running. It still works fine if run whilst Outlook is open (ie GetActiveOleObject('outlook.application')), but just hangs if Outlook is closed.
I am using Office 2019 on all 3 devices, and have tried recompiling with Delphi 12, but that did not solve the issue.
The code that fails is:
try
  Outlook := GetActiveOleObject('outlook.application');
  Created := False;
except  //start outlook if not already running }
  Outlook := CreateOleObject('outlook.application');
  Created := True;
end;

Whenever the CreateOleObject('outlook.application'); line is reached, it never reaches the Created := True; line.
In the notification area, I get an error saying that a program is accessing Outlook, but it is impossible to end the task either by right-clicking the icon in the notification area, or via Task Manager, or by running it in the IDE and terminating it and closing Delphi.
If I run it in the IDE, it sometime works and sometimes hangs.
Any ideas on what might cause this?

Why not checking if Outlook (OUTLOOK.EXE) is running process-wise before relying on OLE?

Does Outlook display a profile selection prompt?

with @AmigoJack comment, try starting Outlook app if not running so no need to create new obj...

admin rights? try to start outlook as admin
